# MongoDB Map Reduce C#

Tags: mapreduce, mongodb-.net-driver

I am currently doing a map-reduce with the c# driver in Mongo.
I have got it working where the JSON is as follows:

```
{ "_id" : CSUUID("ef53b163-699c-462f-9135-b81bad115635"), "value" : { "firstname" : "Joe", "lastname" : "Bloggs", "groupName" : "System Wide Access" } }
```

What I want to do is flatten this object so as I don't have an Id and Value field, I only want the actual properties that are in my read model class.

Here is my code as it is currently:

```
        const string mapUserGroupMember = @"function ()
                                            {
                                              var output = {groupId:this.GroupId, firstname:this.Forename, lastname:this.Surname, groupName:null}
                                              emit(this.GroupId, output);                
                                            }";


        const string mapUserGroupName = @"function ()
                                            {
                                              var output = {groupId:this._id, firstname:null, lastname:null, groupName:this.Name}
                                              emit(this._id, output);                
                                            }";

        var reduceF = @"function(key, values) {
                        var results = {firstname:null, lastname:null , groupName:null};

                        values.forEach(function(v){

                                       if(results.firstname ==null){
                                            results.firstname = v.firstname
                                        }
                                        if(results.lastname ==null){
                                            results.lastname = v.lastname
                                        }
                                        if(results.groupName ==null){
                                            results.groupName = v.groupName
                                        }

                                         });
                                        return results;
                                    };";

        var groupMemberCollection = database.GetCollection("UserGroupMemberReadModel");
        var groupNameCollection = database.GetCollection("UserGroupNameReadModel");

        var options = new MapReduceOptionsBuilder();
        options.SetOutput(MapReduceOutput.Reduce("MergedData"));

        var results = groupNameCollection.MapReduce(mapUserGroupName, reduceF, options);
        results = groupMemberCollection.MapReduce(mapUserGroupMember, reduceF, options);
```

I want to be able to call `var collection = database.GetCollection("MergedData").AsQueryable<ReadModel>();`

Any help would be appreciated.